# sbt cannot resolve dependency from sonatype snapshots

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, sbt

I have looked at related questions and tried the suggestions there. They don't seem to help.

Here is what I have in my build.sbt file:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
...
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark" % "2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
  )
...
```

I have confirmed that repo has the appropriate jar. Here is the output from doing compile in the sbt interpreter:

```
[info] Resolving org.elasticsearch#elasticsearch-spark_2.11;2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: org.elasticsearch#elasticsearch-spark_2.11;2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/aswami/.ivy2/local/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark_2.11/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark_2.11/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/elasticsearch-spark_2.11-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.elasticsearch#elasticsearch-spark_2.11;2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.11:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (/Users/aswami/repos/dtex-datascience/build.sbt#L129)
[warn]        +- com.dtex:analysis_2.11:0.1
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last analysis/*:update for the full output.
[error] (analysis/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.elasticsearch#elasticsearch-spark_2.11;2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

Why does it not try the sonatype-snapshots repo?
What should I do differently to resolve the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify additional resolvers, for sonatype snapshots you could add `resolvers += 
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"` , see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html for more information.

Comment: I already tried this. It does not seem to help. I have tried different variations on specifying the resolver for Sonatype OSS Snapshots. None seem to support resolution of the snapshot JAR.

Comment: For now, I am working around the problem by using unmanaged dependencies, i.e., I am putting the jar in the lib subdirectory under the project. However, I would prefer to use managed dependencies since all my other dependencies are managed.